# Weird issue regarding image in html

Tags: html

I am trying to display an image on my website by using this simple code -

```
<img src="images/google-adwords-icon.png" border="0" alt="google-adwords" />
```

But on webpage, the image is not rendering; instead I am facing a very weird issue - the following code has been tracked by me in firebug -

```
<img class="xnunavyyqyfxajbvnknq" src="images/google-adwords-icon.png" alt="google-adwords" border="0">
```

But when i open this image in photo viewer then image is loaded properly - no issue with it.

How did it happen? I have no idea. How the class automatically added there? What language is it? And firebug says failed to load the given URL. Any idea?

**EDIT -**

1. I am not using any framework - neither PHP nor CSS/Javascript
2. I am not using any WISIWIG text editor.
3. No addon is being used by me.
4. I am working on localhost.
5. Path "images/google-adwords-icon.png" is 100% ok. Any other image on the same level is displaying.

**Problem fixed!** When i changed the file name from "google-adwords-icon.png" to "adwords-icon.png". It was only "google" which doing so weird but nobody knows the exact reason. But fixed it just now. Thanks to all.

Comment: are you sure the src path is correct?

Comment: give site link. let me check what happens

Comment: Any addons that might be doing it?

Comment: well, if you are using a WISIWIG, then it might automatically add a class for styling purposes. I would suggest clearing cache and refreshing.

Comment: path is not correct, no mystery here.

Comment: are you using any framework?